# How to add level 1 of log verbosity in Python code?

Tags: python, logging

I am running this [script](https://github.com/Joker-Jerome/UTMOST/blob/master/single_tissue_covariance.py) using Python/2.7.13-intel-2017a:

```
 python2 single_tissue_covariance.py --weight_db Retina.db --input_folder sample_data/dosage/ --covariance_output sample_data/covariance_external/Retina.txt.gz
INFO - Loading Weights
Killed
```

I am complete novice to Python but it seems the error stems from class ProcessWeightDB(object), and maybe it would be good to add some error handling blocks to make the debugging slightly easier.

Also it seems to me that the code is able to handle different levels of verbosity...Can someone help me came up with solution on how to implement in the code level 1 of log verbosity?

Comment: check [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)

Comment: `python2 single_tissue_covariance.py --help` should give you some insight as to how to interface with the script. but you want to change with `--verbosity n` see line 305 in the linked code you provided.